# Comparing two string in python

Tags: python, string

Is there any in build function in python which enables two compare two string.
i tried comparing two strings using `==` operator but not working.

```
try:
    if company=="GfSE-Zertifizierungen":
        y=2
        if x<y:
            print "**************Same company***********"
            x=x+1
            flag=0
            pass    
        if x==y:
            flag=1
            x=0
            count=count+1
except Exception as e:
     print e
```

This is not even showing any error nor working out.
Can anyone assist me where I m going wrong

Comment: Put a print statement right after `if company=="GfSE-Zertifizierungen":`. See if that gets printed. If it does, you know that the error doesn't lie in that if-test.

Comment: What do `x` and `y` have to do with comparing strings?

Comment: Please review your formatting; indentation is important in Python. What *is* `company`? Note that e.g. `"GfSE-Zertifizierungen" != "GfSE Zertifizierungen"`. Also, you should have as little as possible in the `try` block; move the rest to an `else`.

Comment: Your code, as posted here is mixing tabs and spaces. Be careful, best to stick to **just** spaces. Otherwise you'll end up with inconsistent indentation and that'll only lead to errors.

Answer (score 2):

In python to compare a string you should use the `==` operator.
eg:

```
a = "hello"
b = "hello2"
c = "hello"
```

then

```
a == b # should return False
a == c # should return True
```

Suggestion: print the content of your variable "company" to check what's inside of it. Be sure to have the same case (lower/upper letters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `==` to check both the string are equal or not.
The problem is not with your `if` statement.

```
>>> company="GfSE-Zertifizierungen"
>>> if company == "GfSE-Zertifizierungen":
         print "OK"
    else:
         print "NOT OK"
```

Output:

```
OK
```

You can use `debugger` to see whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator for strings in python compares each letter of one string to another. If they are all the same, the string is equal.

The only two possibilities here are that you are not reaching the line

```
if company=="GfSE-Zertifizierungen":
```

or company is not actually the same.

To help troubleshoot, add something like:

```
try:
    print "Got to here"
    print company
    if company=="GfSE-Zertifizierungen":
        y=2
        ....
```